# Что такое «купаленные донья»?

Tags: значения, этимология, лингвистика

В стихотворении Пастернака «Определение поэзии» есть строфа:

Всё, что ночи так важно сыскать
На глубоких купаленных доньях,
И звезду донести до садка
На трепещущих мокрых ладонях.

Я никак не могу понять значение прилагательного «купаленные». Что оно обозначает? Это неологизм?

Comment: если честно, то это Пастернаку просто было нужно придумать рифму к "ладонях"

Comment: probably, here is the reference not only just to a baths/waters (купальня), but to the pagan-Slavic holiday "Купала". https://youtu.be/DE2K-SxW5eM

Comment: возможно, отсылка на Купалу и те ритуалы

Answer (score 7):

«Купаленный» — прилагательное от «купальня».

«Донья» — множественное число от «дно».

Анализ стихотворения «Определение поэзии» можно почитать [тут](https://m.studme.org/211113/literatura/analiz_stihotvoreniya_pasternaka_opredelenie_poezii).